# Difference between / and // directories in bash OSX

Tags: macos, bash

I was working in the bash terminal on my system (OSX 10.8.3 / bash version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)) and I accidentally typed "cd //" instead of "cd /" to get back to the root directory.

Strange thing was that it took me to "//" which when I listed looked exactly like "/".

So my questions are:
 Is there any semantic difference betweens these two paths?
 What if anything is the purpose of these two paths? 
 and/or is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Unix and derivatives, multiple slashes following each other carry the same meaning as one slash. OS X is certified Unix, and thus follows that specification.

From the [Single Unix Specification about the path name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266):

> [A path] has an optional beginning slash, followed by zero or more filenames separated by slashes. A pathname may optionally contain one or more trailing slashes. Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.

The only special case is a path beginning with `//`. Its interpretation is up to the implementation (see [Pathname Resolution in the SUS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)):

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Comment: NOTE: the most seen place where // is special is cygwin, where it is the analog of the \\filer\volume\ [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#UNC_in_Windows) path.